# GroovyWS web service consumer client does not run with JDK 1.7

Tags: javac, gradle, java-7, groovyws

Have already searched this website and others but could not find the answer.

I have a simple GroovyWS web service consumer based on the example code at

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Consuming+a+web+service

I am using Gradle for the build and have groovyws 0.5.2 as a dependency

Now when I run the example on a Windows 7 machine with Java JDK 1.6 installed the example code works.

However when I run the **exact** same test code (cloned from github) on my laptop which has Java JDK 1.7 installed I get the following errors on the console

```
javac: target release 1.5 conflicts with default source release 1.7
Jun 11, 2012 10:27:28 PM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory createClient
SEVERE: Could not compile java files for http://www.webservicex.net/uklocation.asmx?WSDL
```

I have tried the following settings in my Gradle build.gradle file

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
```

but no joy :(

So I am not sure where to change the javac compile settings for GroovyWS?

Comment: This problem went away when I updated my groovy version

Comment: what are the dependencies of groovyws itself?